# How to fit output data into dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Following code gives the name of cities. Now, I want to fit that output data into pandas dataframe.

Python Jupyter Notebook 3+

```
import geoip2.database
reader = geoip2.database.Reader('F:/GeoLite2-City_20190305/GeoLite2-City.mmdb')

for user in data:
    try:
        reader.city(user[1]).city.names["en"]
    except KeyError:
        print(user[1],"  No City")
    else:
        print(user[1],"  ",reader.city(user[1]).city.names["en"])
```

I want output as
e.g.

```
ip         city

12345       Ohio
```